# Have jQuery actively select divs whose classes live update?

Tags: jquery

I am working my way through a jQuery book right now, and I am trying to make some basic markup for my website as practice.

What would be the best way to actively select the class containing lets say the word "active" at the end of it. I was going to use the live() method but after looking that up on jQuery's website, they say it's now obsolete?  How else can I tell jQuery to keep looking for the class  that ends with the word "active" within a parent div after the DOM finishes initially loading?

The reason why it needs to keep looking is, I am using some open-source jQuery slider for my front page, and it adds the word "active" onto the end of the class of the div that's currently displaying the shown image.

Comment: live have been replace by 'on' in jquery 1.7

Comment: Check out this quick sample fiddle and the use of `on`: http://jsfiddle.net/pV2CZ/

Comment: _"I was going to use the live() method but after looking that up on jQuery's website, they say it's now obsolete?"_ - And in the sentence after the [`.live()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/live) tells you that `.live()` is deprecated it tells you what to use instead...

Comment: Your comments are very useful, I like the Fiddle linked to, seeing live code examples really help me understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements that end with a certain value using the following:

```
$("[class$='active']")
```

If you want to only select top-level `div` elements, you can use the following:

```
$("body > div[class$='active']")
```

I'm not sure what the `live()` event has to do with what you're trying to do.

---

**References:**

- [Attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)
- [Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)